# Can you force Edge (Chromium) as the WebView when using Xamarin across iOS and Android?

Tags: xamarin, microsoft-edge

I have a requirement for our Xamarin app that is deployed across iOS and Android to use Edge only for all WebView traffic. Currently WebView is using the device default browser (iOS: Safari, Android: Chrome). Is it possible to force Edge as the default browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Webview uses Safari(iOS)  , Chrome(Android) , Edge(Windows) as default browser , if we load the link on webview , it uses default browser and we can change nothing , however you could take a look at [Xamarin.Essentials: Browser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/open-browser?tabs=android), it opens the website outside of the app ,we can choose the external launcher as browser (you should install Edge app first on your device).

```
await Browser.OpenAsync("https://www.google.com", BrowserLaunchMode.External);
```

[image]